# How i stop the notification counter to zero in Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on notifications in JavaScript when i push notifications it shows the counter but when i want that when i open one notification the number of counter decreases till zero for example first counter shows number seven means seven notifications there but when i open one of them it shows counter with value 6 and so on till it reaches counter value zero but in my case i have write a line of code when the counter value reaches to zero it goes to negative values like -1 -2 -3 and so on?how i stop this to only zero counter value?

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#noti_Counter').html(function(i, val) { 
        return val*1+1 
    });
```

Comment: the problem is not in this function because it just calculate the returned value. the problem is in the parameters of this function... from where ```val``` is obtained?

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what your rest of the code looks like, this could be done different way and some better than others. But purely based on what is posted in the question here is what you can do to make sure your value doesn't go below 0:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#noti_Counter').html(function(i, val) { 
       let ret = val*1+1;
       return (ret < 0) ? 0 : ret;         
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Nawed brother actually my problem is that when i open one notification i expect that counter value now decrease by one ok but when so on i reached the value of counter to zero it goes to negative values like -1 -2 - 3 i only want to stop this thing that values are not going to be negative just stop there at zero. :) Hope so now you understand my question

Comment: @WaseemAhmad that's what this answer does - stops at zero

Comment: Is my answer not working? it simply says if value is less than 0 then return 0 else return the value.

Comment: @WaseemAhmad if it is not changing the result then either the changes are not saved, or this function is not responsible of showing that number. simply return 1; all the time and see if your counter always show 1. If not then this function is not the correct one.

Comment: @jawed khan brother it works now but with the little change in your code that is 
val*1+1;

Comment: @WaseemAhmad What needs to be changed? that line is the exact copy of your code assigned to a variable. All I added is if the result of your calculation is below zero then return 0.

Comment: sorry sorry brother i say it now works with little change in line of your code that val*1-1;